# Segmentation network in Keras converges to single class during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement RefineNet in Keras with Tensorflow backend. I am using the ResNet-101 front-end and pre-trained weights from https://gist.github.com/flyyufelix/65018873f8cb2bbe95f429c474aa1294. The model compiles successfully, but does not converge during training: it always converges to a single class after just 1 to 5 training steps.

List of stuff I tried / though of:

- The input data is one-hot encoded
- The input images have the correct corresponding masks
- Loss function is categorical crossentropy
- The pre-trained weights are correct, the front-end is correctly classifying input images (e.g. cats)
- Freezing / unfreezing the front-end layers does not seem to make a difference
- Different optimizers (Adam, SGD), different learning rates (0.01 - 0.000001)
- The network does not even converge to / overfit on a single training sample
- Class imbalance: I tried using a weighted loss, didn't help. Also, the network does not always converge to the largest class.
- Checked the network graphs and compared them to the architecture from the RefineNet paper.
- Could be some sort of initialization issue, but Keras' default initialization is glorot_uniform for the kernels and zeros for the biases, can't think of anything better than that.
- The ReLUs could have all died, but that should not happen after just a few training steps, right? I tried LeakyRelU, didn't help.
- Tried different input sizes, batch sizes, random cropping, aspect ratios (was getting somewhat desperate at this point).
- Tried inputting random noise, same behavior.

The last point makes me think that the architecture is simply disregarding the input but I have no idea where, how and why.

Example output during training:

```
Training:
Step 0, loss 15.566238403320312, acc 0.012790679931640625
Step 1, loss 9.91278076171875, acc 0.36734771728515625
Step 2, loss 10.994621276855469, acc 0.27989959716796875
Step 3, loss 10.00101375579834, acc 0.3611602783203125
Step 4, loss 11.439224243164062, acc 0.2010345458984375
Step 5, loss 11.397968292236328, acc 0.229278564453125
Step 6, loss 9.844161987304688, acc 0.3711433410644531
Step 7, loss 9.981706619262695, acc 0.36286163330078125
Step 8, loss 11.335559844970703, acc 0.21475982666015625
Step 9, loss 9.997631072998047, acc 0.3608970642089844
...
```

The complete code can be found in the following Google Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OlujuKZYhRaTm9h7rHAPEi9gkiYmQLR_

I've tried to make it as easy as possible to reproduce the problem.

Any help / ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Batch Normalization layers after the conv layers solved the issue.